# Generating PHP/MySQL Reference ID

Tags: php, sql, mysql

In PHP/MySQL, what's the best way to generate a unique reference ID so that when a person submits his info to the database, he gets a reference number to follow up with his request?

I am already using the auto-increment feature from the database since the data needs to be unique every time a user submits information, but then I need to pick that specific data from the database in order to retrieve that incremented value and display it with PHP.

Comment: The auto-increment column needs to be the primary key for the table.

Comment: Using the auto_increment makes sense because it's already unique. But for security you might want to give the user a hashed key so that users don't attempt to see others' issues by incrementing or decrementing their issue number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the auto_increment value you can execute `select last_insert_id()` after your insert.

last_insert_id() is a mysql function that returns the auto increment value from the last insert.

As others have noted some mysql libraries provide their own method for getting the last insert id

Comment: What if 12 people submit the form at the same time?  Would there be a conflict?

Comment: last_insert_id() is maintained per database connection. Since the connection is not shared between server instances each simultaneous submit has its own connection.  Using PHP's persistent connections shouldn't change this.

Answer (score 1):

rexem's comment is correct; then if you're using the basic mysql commands in PHP, you can use

`$id = mysql_insert_id()`

to retrieve the last insert'ed row's ID number (based on the primary key of that table).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with the `auto_increment` field that you already have : it's a solution that works fine -- maybe concatenating it with something, to get, for instance "`CMD123456`", which is more "human-readable".

To get the last generated `auto_increment` for the currently active connection to the DB, you can use the [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function -- provided you are working with the family of `mysql_*` functions.

Just call it after you have done your insert query, and it'll get you the value of the `auto_increment` that has been generated by/for that one.

If using `mysqli_*`, you'll need [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), and, if using PDO, you'll work with [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).